# Kudu console for Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have a website hosted on azure. I am using the kudu console to manage deployments. I normally use visual studio to deploy to the cloud directly through a publish profile. But right now, that option is not available to me.

My problem is I have to update a static json file. I am using the kudu console to make my changes and save it. Post the changes, I have restarted the site using both the azure portal and the kudu site extensions, but I am unable to view my changes on the site. It still refers to the older version of the json.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're using a Cloud Service or a Web App? Kudu is only supported on Web Apps but your title says Cloud Service. If Web App, are you able to repro the issue on a clean new app as well?

Comment: Are you modifying a file that is located on D:\home\site\wwwroot ?